# c# Selenium Chrome - click buttons with classes and subclasses

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

***1st question :***
I've been through the xpath tutorials and checked many other posts nad forums. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm simply trying to find the following element by xpath:

```
<button ng-show="vm.enableSkip(row)" ng-click="vm.skipTask(row.workItemId)" title="Skip" class="btn btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-right text-success"></span></button>
```

I've tried  such as:

```
Element_on_site = findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Skip']"));
```

But this doesn't work .

Should i add just element name before ? Like this? :

```
Element_on_site = findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Skip']"));
```

I can't test it right now because  I don't have access to this site only in
work.
Can someone just help me to get this Click without errors?

**2nd question  :** 
 HTML code page like this :
[image]
If this is problem i can rewrite it in code . Just tell me and i delete picture and make this code.
The question is : How can i just write clicking Skip element  **where  :**

`class  = "ng-scope"` and subclass  (of ng-scope) is `class = "ng-binding"` and  element inside `ng-binding  = "outgoingEventExecutor"`

exacly html code I'm talking about :

```
<a href="" ng-click="vm.showProcessDiagram(row.executor)" class="ng-binding">outgoingEventExecutor</a>
```

How can i do that when My **where** is available then Just make my Click with ***1st question?***

**EDIT 1 about comment down**
I just want something like this :

```
//tr[@class='ng-scope']/td[@class='ng-binding']/ == **outgoingEventExecutor**
```

but don't know how to write to  check this path > and then if there is this Executor then just /button[@title='Skip']

**EDIT 2**
Okay, I'll literally explain what I'm trying to do and I want to get.
On the site I have several blocks of html text that look identical(look screen up) and differ only in one thing. The thing that differs is this piece of html code:

```
<a href="" ng-click="vm.showProcessDiagram(row.executor)" class="ng-binding">outgoingEventExecutor</a>
```

And just the name "outgoingEventExecutor" is different for each code block.
All I want to do is click on the Skip button which is in the class (tr class = "ng-scope") and contains the text of the link - as you said: exacly: "outgoingEventExecutor". I think now you understand what I'm doing. Thank you!

Comment: You have a missing ) in your examples

Comment: @powerpete You are right. I just edited and correct this. Can u just help me with my questions?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if somewhere in your dom you have another button with @title='Skip'. Try to be a little more explicit with your XPath. Give this guy a shot:

```
//tr[@class='ng-scope']/td[@class='text-center']/button[@title='Skip']
```

This will give it some more direction on the specific button if there just so happens to be multiple elements on the page as usually in tables there are

Comment: OK but what about **class="ng-binding">outgoingEventExecutor<** Can i just do this Path where it's name like this?  Can you just look on screen  @up and check it? I just want to include only when this Executor is inside this class go check and then  button[@title='Skip']

Comment: @Michael The outgoingEventExecutor is the text of the a link. You can utilize the text in the dom by the text() functionality of XPaths. This is by going like this 

    "//a[text()='outgoingEventExecutor']" If you are more explicit with the specific dom element you are looking for I can help more but your question is a little confusing.

Comment: Check Edit 2 in main post i said you clear what i want to do.